# Formatting string which is in double curly braces

Tags: python, string-formatting

I've got following short code I need to execute

```
isin = 'US0028241000'
payload = f'[{"idType":"ID_ISIN", "idValue": "{isin}"}]'
```

It outputs a `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`

I also tried :

```
payload = '[{"idType":"ID_ISIN", "idValue": "{}"}]'.format(isin)
```

This one does not work as well.
My thought is that it's because the curly braces located within a dict. How can I execute this piece?

Comment: You may be interested in the [related documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) :
> If you need to include a brace character in the literal text, it can be escaped by doubling: {{ and }}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your title alludes to the solution. Inside an f-string, you need to use `{{` and `}}` for literal curly braces, but you never introduce them.

```
>>> f'[{{"idType":"ID_ISIN", "idValue": "{isin}"}}]'
'[{"idType":"ID_ISIN", "idValue": "US0028241000"}]'
```

That said, don't construct JSON values using string formatting tools; use the `json` module.

```
>>> import json
>>> json.dumps([{'idType': 'ID_ISIN', 'idValue': isin}])
'[{"idType": "ID_ISIN", "idValue": "US0028241000"}]'
```

Comment: Thank you. the json piece was super helpful!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the curly braces.

To escape them, try:

```
payload = f'[{{"idType":"ID_ISIN", "idValue": "{isin}"}}]'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
isin = 'US0028241000'
payload = f'[{{"idType":"ID_ISIN", "idValue": "{isin}"}}]'
print(payload)
```

for ignoring any curly braces while formating the string just wrap it with a `{}`

Answer (score 1):

`f` string consider whatever inside of the curly braces `{}` is a python expression.

The problem here also is the same, you are trying to put curly braces as a dictionary but `f` string considers it as an expression. When it tries to interpret we are getting `ValueError: Invalid format specifier`.

**Example 1:**
Trying to put `list` variable inside `f` string

```
l = [1,2,3]
`f'{l}'`
```

**Example 2:**
Trying to put `dict` inside `f` string

You should use **double curly braces**.

```
`f'[{{"idType":"ID_ISIN", "idValue": "{isin}"}}]'`
```

But if you declared `dict` in some variable then you probably will be using as below:

```
out = {"idType":"ID_ISIN", "idValue": f"{isin}"}
f'{out}'
```